# Why loading naturalWidth of an image returns the width of previously uploaded image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have successfully showed a preview of an uploaded image. Now I need to know its `naturalWidth`.

However, when I access the `naturalWidth` of my image it returns the width of the previously uploaded image.

E.g: first uploaded image has a width of 100, second image has 200 width. When I upload the first image, the alerted value is 0. When I upload the second image the value is 100.

Here is a part of my code.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    $('#img').css("display", "block").attr('src', e.target.result);
    var width = document.querySelector('#img').naturalWidth;
    alert(width);
};
reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must wait for your <img> has loaded before doing anything with it, like accessing its naturalWidth.

Note also that you absolutely don't need a FileReader here, create a blob:// URL from your File:

```js
// onchange = evt => {
  $('#img')
    .css("display", "block")
    .attr('src', URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
    .one('load', function(e) => {
      const width = this.naturalWidth;
      alert(width);
    });
```